# WHAT İS "error: expected '(' after 'if' if else(y>z)" THİS ERROR

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm new at the software and I took this error in visual studio code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x,y,z;
    printf("1. sayiyi giriniz");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("2. sayiyi giriniz");
    scanf("%f",&y);
    printf("3. sayiyi giriniz");
    scanf("%f",&z);
    if(x>y && x>z)
    {
    printf("%f en buyuk sayi ", x);
    }
    if else(y>z)
    {
    printf("%f en buyuk sayi ", y);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("%f en buyuk sayi ", z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is pretty clear: `if else(y>z)` is not valid syntax, b/c (for starters) you need a `(` after `if`.

Answer (score 1):

`if else` is not valid C (or C++) sytnax. You probably meant `else if`.

Comment: yes ı want wrote else if ı learn at now correct thank forgive me for my english thank you brother